# Should we represent binary trees using arrays, or vice-versa?

Tags: arrays, tree

My current understanding is that an array (one-dimensional) can be used to represent a left-balanced binary tree. In other words, from the way the nodes are arranged in a binary tree diagram, we can fill up the positions of the array.

However, is this correct? Rather, should we use a binary tree diagram to represent the elements in an array? In this case, we create the binary tree diagram using the elements in the array, and use the formulas *l = 2n + 1* and *r = 2n + 2* (where *n* = array index of parent node, *l* = array index of left child node and *r* = array index of right child node) to know how to determine the array indices of the child nodes of a particular parent.

Which is correct then - using arrays to represent binary tree diagrams, or using binary tree diagrams to represent arrays? Or are both ways correct?

Comment: You are confusing a concept with its programming implementation.  Binary trees are a set of organizational strategies for data.  The array is one specific programming implementation for one of these strategies.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Riddhesh and ryanyuyu, for your answers and advice.

After further research, I realized that a left-balanced binary tree (also known as a "Complete Binary Tree") **can** be represented in programming code as a one-dimensional array. The purpose of this representation is for ease of implementation of code that manipulates the nodes of the Complete Binary Tree.

Conversely, a one-dimensional array can also be conceptually represented as a Complete Binary Tree. The purpose of such a representation is for ease of implementation of code that sorts the elements of the array using binary tree theories. An example of this is "Heap Sorting" where a Complete Binary Tree is transformed into a min- or max-Heap that is completely sorted.

Thanks for all your help :)

Useful links :
https://www.cpp.edu/~ftang/courses/CS241/notes/heap.htm
http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs3114/Fall09/wmcquain/Notes/T03a.BinaryTreeTheorems.pdf

P.S.: sorry for using the Answer option to post this. I was unable to post this as a comment due to character limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Binary tree from Array using your formula does not help me imagine easily how a Binary tree will look whereas from the way the nodes are arranged in a binary tree diagram, if we fill up the positions of the array it is easy to visualize.

We use arrays or linked list or any other data structure to bring a real world problem to be mapped in programming. We do not do vice-versa.